# sending message to my phone when Lambda trigger runned to count running ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, triggers, message, aws-event-bridge

1. I set a lambda code to count number of running ec2 like below:
   [image]
2. I want to run this lambda funtion every day in specific time, so i triggered
   'Eventbridge'. I tested this, and it worked well.
   [image]
3. The result of lambda function is like

...

**Function Logs**

START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST

Running:  1

END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Im running 1 ec2 now, so the result said 'Running: 1'
Also, i can check the result like image below.
[image]

4. The last thing i want to do is
   getting the log information to my phone.

Espacially, 'Running:  1' this parts.

More, i want to get text message to my phone like below:

**Today's running ec2 is 1**

How can i get this message to my phone?
(The lambda is going to run every day, so i should recieve the phone message also everyday.)

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS SDK to send a message to a Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic. You can then subscribe your phone to that topic. So that whenever your topic receives a message it will be sent to your phone.

Comment: Hiw can i get a 'running : 1' part as a parameter??

Comment: Because the number of running ec2 gonna change everyday